# Function to choose items from two columns that sum to a set total in column 1 and average to a number in column 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns with a large number of rows. I am looking to choose rows (two elements) such that the items chosen from column 1 will sum to a set number and the  items from column two average to a certain number (or as close as possible in each case). The constraint is that you you must take both elements from each row i.e. you cannot take a column 1 number without taking the corresponding column 2 value.
Shown below is an example where the number is the row number. And I give the column 1 and 2 numbers

```
 1. 1,2
 2. 3,5
 3. 2,4
 4. 5,1
```

If the sum of column 1 was set to 3 and the average was set to 3 also then we could take row 1 and 3 as the sum of column 1 rows 1 and 3 is equal to 3 and the corresponding column 2 numbers, 2 and 4 average to 3.

I attempted to look into some sumproduct solutions however I have not been able to find a solution that incorporates both the sum and average at the same time

Sample Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sImi.jpg

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide us with starting data, expected result, your attempts, their results and how they fail to meet the desired result?

Comment: Could you provide a sample file or screenshots about your problem? It's not clearly.

Comment: Hi, sample screenshot added. I want to pick rows such that the sum of the column 1 elements picked equals the sum setpoint and at the same time the elements in column 2 (from the same row as the column 1 elements) averages to the average setpoint. Does this make sense? Apologies I know it is a long description.